# Modificar formato de un AVG al imprimirlo

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo una base de datos la cual utilizo para hacer una consulta e imprimir el promedio de todos los valores de una columna en mi página, mediante el siguiente código.

```
<?php
 $pmqual = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT AVG(opqualify) as average_rating FROM operaciones WHERE usersending = '$user' ORDER BY operationid");
 $prom = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pmqual);
?>
<li>Calificación promedio: <span><?php echo $prom['average_rating'];?> <i class="fa fa-star qualstar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
```

Y en mi página se muestra del siguiente modo, junto a otros datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber si es posible cambiar el formato en que se muestra ya que desearia que se muestre con simplemente uno o dos decimales, no 4 como aparece actualmente.

La estructura de la columna que almacena estos datos es un INT de '1' ya que es un dígito que va desde 1 a 5 (una calificación de 1 a 5 estrellas típica).

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa la función [`round()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) de PHP para redondear el dato.

```
<?php
 $pmqual = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT AVG(opqualify) as average_rating FROM operaciones WHERE usersending = '$user' ORDER BY operationid");
 $prom = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pmqual);
?>
<li>Calificación promedio: 
<span><?php echo round($prom['average_rating'], 2);?> 
<i class="fa fa-star qualstar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Funcionó perfectamente. Sinceramente desconocía esta función. Muchas gracias!